# Can astyanax return ordered column names?

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

Using com.netflix.astyanax, I add entries for a given row as follows:

```
final ColumnListMutation<String> columnList = m.withRow(columnFamily, key);
columnList.putEmptyColumn(columnName);
```

Later I retrieve all my columns with:

```
  final OperationResult<ColumnList<String>> operationResult = keyspace
          .prepareQuery(columnFamily).getKey(key).execute();
  operationResult.getResult().getColumnNames();
```

The following correctly return all the columns I have added but the columns are not ordered accordingly to when they were entered in the database.  Since each column has a timestamp associated to it, there ought to be a way to do exactly this but I don't see it.  Is there?

Note: If there isn't, I can always change the code above to:

```
columnList.putColumn(ip,new Date());
```

and then retrieve the column values, order them accordingly, but that seems cumbersome, inefficient, and silly since each column already has a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I know from PlayOrm that if you do column Slices, it returns those in order.  In fact, playorm uses that do enable S-SQL in partitions and basically batches the column slicing which comes back in order or reverse order depending on how requested.  You may want to do a column slice from 0 to MAXLONG.

I am not sure about getting the row though.  I haven't tried that.

oh, and PlayOrm is just a mapping layer on top of astyanax though not really relational and more noSql'ish really as demonstrated by it's patterns pages

http://buffalosw.com/wiki/Patterns-Page/

Comment: Thanks.  We have already quite a bit of code written using the com.netflix.astyanax library.  Will all that code still run if we just rely on the PlayOrm library instead?  And do you know whether there is definitely not a solution for my problem (apart from the workaround I suggested) if I stick with the astyanax library?

Comment: it's much like hibernate so like hibernate EXCEPT it follows nosql patterns.  If you define your entites correctly, it most likely will map correctly.  Also, like hibernate, there is nothing preventing you from doing both side by side and passing in your astyanax to playorm so you can use both side by side.  PlayOrm unlike astyanax also has a flush feature so all your writes go out at the end instead of 1,2,3(ie. what happens if it failes after write 1 before write 2....data corruption?)

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra will never order your columns in "insertion order".

Columns are always ordered lowest first. It also depends on how cassandra interprets your column names. You can define the interpretation with the comparator you set when defining your column family.

From what you gave it looks you use String timestamp values. If you simply serialized your timestamps as e.g. "123141" and "231" be aware that with an `UTF8Type` comparator "231">"123131".

Better approach: Use Time-based UUIDs as column names, as many examples for Time-series data in Cassandra propose. Then you can use the `UUIDType` comparator.

```
 CREATE COLUMN FAMILY timeseries_data
 WITH comparator = UUIDType
 AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type;
```